# Populate column with same value without using cell references

Tags: vba, loops

I need to populate values under a column named "Funded" through to the last row at the end of the dataset. The column can be located anywhere on the worksheet so I cannot use cell references.

```
  Dim shtA As Worksheet
  Dim LastCol As Long
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Set shtA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Financial")
  LastCol = shtA.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  lastRow = shtA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



 'Add column header for Funded 
 Dim fund As Long
 On Error Resume Next
 fund = Cells.Find(What:="", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Funded"
 On Error GoTo 0

'Loop through Funded to get column number
  Dim fund As Long
  Dim a As Long
  For a = 1 To LastCol
    If LCase(shtA.Cells(1, a).Value) = "funded" Then
        fund = a
        Exit For 
    End If
  Next a

'Populate Funded column with "1" to the last row
  Dim aa As Long
  For aa = 2 To lastRow
    shtA.Cells(a, Funded + 1).Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Next aa
```

Comment: Add Option Explicit to all of your modules and classes, then use Debug/Compile. Is the last loop's Funded variable declared?

Comment: Thanks for this tip--I didn't know about it. The variable seems to be declared since I don't get an error for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a new column, header and content:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Financial").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = "Funded"
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value = 1
End With
```

Comment: Yes! This worked wonderfully. I still get so confused on which approach to use when using VBA. I see I was making it more complicated than necessary. Thank you!

Comment: I admit this is a bit of a "code golf" answer - it would maybe be clearer if a range variable were assigned first, instead of using the With block, and `CurrentRegion` is not the most reliable method of finding the last row, as it will be sensitive to any blank rows in your dataset.